# How should I modify my question about orks on the step to reopen it?

Tags: support, close-reasons

In this question [How can human and orcish tribes cooexist on the steppe?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/179294/how-can-human-and-orcish-tribes-cooexist-on-the-steppe) I tried to ask how orkish tribes could coexist on the steppe with a human khanate.

In my mind this is a question about nations and culture, something which acording to the faq explicitly are on topic.

Despite this the question got closed with being to story based.

Which elements of the question is the problem and how can I edit to remove them?

Comment: You just got it reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, story based.  As your query is written, the answers will largely focus on the choices the Khan makes: why hasn't he sought to obliterate them? In other words, the question is leading towards answers that speak to the choices and actions of individual characters within a narrative framework.

An example answer would be: *the Khan has not chosen to obliterate or drive the Orcs away because they're kind of dumb and make good buffers against potential enemies; plus, if you're strong willed, they do what you tell them to do*.

Another example answer would be: *the Khan has not chosen to obliterate or drive the Orcs away because his favourite wife is an Orc and she's the real power behind the throne*.

So ya: you're going to need to edit your query to change its focus from actions of characters to fundamentals of society & culture.

I think it's kind of obvious, but I'd start by deleting the bit where you ask "why hasn't the Khan slaughtered or driven the Orcs out?" That's a dead ringer for story based closure right there!

Comment: I have tried to edit based on this feedback. Does it look better now?

Comment: Does it really matter at this point? I notice you've already award the big green checkmark to an answer, so, why are you even concerned about reopening the question? Why am I wasting my time trying to help you get that done? For future reference: don't award the big green check mark until at least two or three days have passed since the time you ask a question. Maybe even a week! The idea is to leave your question open so that it can gather numerous answers for you to choose from, and not everyone is reading your question the instant you write it.